# How can I set a Gigabit network instead of the 100Mb?

Tags: local-area-network, gigabit-ethernet, hardware

I'd like to know what kind of hardware I'll need to set up a Gigabit network in the company I work in.
We're 12 workers with a few splitters and 3 servers.
We already have a Gigabit router and 1 splitter.
Do I need new cables?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What in this context is a "Splitter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your network completely Gigabit, you will need all routers and switches to be Gigabit capable. You will also need Gigabit capable network cards in all machines.

Cat 5 cabling is able to support 1000-BaseT, however Cat 5e may give slightly better perforamnce

Comment: Thanks again.
How can I see the difference between the cables? I mean Cat 5, Cat 5e or Cat 6?

Comment: Unfortunately there is very little visible difference. You will often have to rely on looking at the text on the side of the cable to determine its type.

Comment: you need rather fiber optic cables possibly.

Comment: 1000Mbit speeds are perfectly possible with cat 5 cabling, there is no need for fibre